# How might I use jQuery to move table row elements around in some way?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>  
    <td>something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>something else</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

now based on an id that is in the td i want to move the tr's around so that they are in the position held by the id. any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: ...what does that mean? Should the <tr>s have ID attributes?

Comment: The `tr`s are already in the position held by the `id`s that are contained in the `td`s... in much the same way that Europe is already in the position held by the Paris which is in France. Do your IDs have ordinal rank or something?

Comment: I've been reading that first sentence after the code for a while now, and just can't understand it.  An upvote for the valiant people who tried to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the tr by using the parent() function. For example,

```
$("#td-id").parent().appendTo("table");
```

will move the tr containing the td with the id "td-id" to the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Not good for ordering of large tables, but this worked for me when i wrote it a while back.  You would be ordering on something different (the row id) so you will have to change it to suite your needs.

the first argument is the table you want to sort, the second is the column you would sort on.

you would change all the cIndex stuff to use your rowid instead.

```
function SortTable(stable, cIndex)
{
    var rows = $(stable).find("tr");
    var count = $(rows).size();

    for (var i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    {
        var r1 = $(rows[i]);
        var r2 = $(rows[i + 1]);

        var td1 = $(r1).find("td")[cIndex];
        var td2 = $(r2).find("td")[cIndex];

        var d1 = parseInt($(td1).html());
        var d2 = parseInt($(td2).html());

        if (d1 < d2)
        {
            var t = rows[i];
            rows[i] = rows[i + 1]
            rows[i + 1] = t;
            i = -1;
        }
    }

    var tbody = $(stable);
    tbody.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        $(tbody).append(rows[i]);
    }
}
```